# jquery and dynamic loaded site content

Tags: jquery

I have list of users on my page. When user move on bottom of page, jquery load next users - like this:

```
jQuery(function() {
    if ($('.pagination').length) {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var url;
            url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href');
            if (url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50) {
                $('.pagination').text("Fetching more products...");
                return $.getScript(url);
            }
        });
    }
    return $(window).scroll();
});

$(document).on("ready page:change", function() {
    $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
        animation: 'grow'
    });
});
```

For users photo i use tooltip to load title of this img. But tooltip works only for photo that has been loaded on the first page load. When i go on the bottom of page and load new users , they havent got tooltip. Where i should search for answer to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the scroll function after the images are fully loaded..call the tooltip function again

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var url;
  url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href');
  if (url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50) {
    $('.pagination').text("Fetching more products...");

    $.getScript(url); //dont return change the logic
       $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
    animation: 'grow'
});
   }

});
```

Comment: becuase the return statment is preventing it...change the logic

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getScript(url, function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
     console.log(data); //data returned
      console.log(textStatus); //success
      console.log(jqxhr.status); //200
      console.log('Load was performed.');
    $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
      animation: 'grow'
    });

   });
```

now its works